# Mantaflow Simulation: Fire and Smoke not rendering in Eeevee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I am learning how to use Blender (2.8) on a macbook pro 2017 and have recently attempted to put together my first explosion using the following tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCdQgREfVq8&t=2s

I was able to follow through without issue except that the rendering is done in `cycles` which is too demanding for my macbook (rendering a single image shows as taking up to ~8 hours) so I want to render instead in `eevee`. I've baked the simulation but I can't seem to get what's in my `viewport` to show in my `render` when using `eevee`. `cycles` shows up fine. I am sure this is most likely a setting or misunderstanding of how I have arranged the elements. Was hoping someone could lead me in the right direction.

I've attached my blender file for reference [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18naaHIhx7rDWGBLAp7A30o-2tO0Hw-He). Thank you. Below are images as well for reference to show how I am able to see in `viewport` my explosion but not in `render`.

RENDER
[image]

VIEWPORT
[image: VIEWPORT]

Answer (score 0):

Seeing from your file it seems that your simulation domain does not have a shader, that's why.
At that point of the tutorial the dude creates the shaders.(below)

https://youtu.be/YCdQgREfVq8?t=420